# Cholesky LDLT decomposition and B-orthogonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I know that it is possible to B-orthogonalize a matrix X via a standard LL<sup>T</sup> decomposition:

1) M = X<sup>T</sup>BX

2) U = chol(M)

3) answer = XU<sup>-1</sup>

How can I use LDL<sup>T</sup> decomposition for this?

Comment: What are your abbreviations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dense ${X}_{n \times k}$ and a sparse symmetric positive-definite matrix ${B}_{n \times n}$, we wish to compute a dense matrix S of the same dimensions and column space as X such that: S<sup>T</sup>BS = Identity // *this is a defenition of the B-orthogonalisation*

And we have the [LDLT-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition_2) only. I will use U instead of L<sup>T</sup>

Then, X<sup>T</sup>BX = U<sup>T</sup>DU = U<sup>T</sup>D<sup>1/2</sup>D<sup>1/2</sup>U = U<sup>T</sup>D<sup>1/2</sup>S<sup>T</sup>BSD<sup>1/2</sup>U

Therefore, X = SD<sup>1/2</sup>U ===> S = X(D<sup>1/2</sup>U)<sup>-1</sup> = XU<sup>-1</sup>(D<sup>-1</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup>